# using NFS over unreliable networks (wifi/mobile)

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, nfs

I have a NFS server at home (and an openvpn connection that only works outside of home).

My phone (Jolla) is basically Linux, and has mobile data/wifi/usb network capability.

Basically, I want to NFS mount from the phone to my server, so that I can see a movie/music stored on the NFS server.

Ideally, it would be nice if I don't have network, that it stops, but proceeds playing when I get connectivity back. (hopefully the player has some buffering that eliminates the timeout from switching from wifi to openvn, for instance).

The important part here is the **reliability/stability**, I don't care much about performance.

NFS server is in network 10.73.98.0/24. openvpn network (10.73.99.0/24) can route to it directly, openvpn connectivity is rejected inside LAN network, so that it doesn't conflict.

Considering the following options for network connectivity:

- usb-network via PC (source network 192.168.7.0/24, MASQUERADED to 10.73.98.0/24 network)
- wifi connection at home (in LAN, source network 10.73.98.0/24)
- mobile data connection (dynamic ip, openvpn network 10.73.99.0/24)
- wifi outside home (openvpn network 10.73.99.0/24)

afaik NFS over UDP will not worry about routing, but will need the same IP address (possibly?) for the mount to survive network...

Now, I've also looked at fscache in the hope that it would cache at blocklevel and store blocks (possibly with some readahead from the NFS file?). but it looks like it's storing at filelevel.

The current tests don't survive moving out of wifi range and back in, for instance. even after waiting for a while...

What would be the **best mount options** I should try? Should I look at some form of automounting too? What about **intr** or **soft/hard** or **TCP/UDP**.. should I tunnel it **always over openvpn** for reliability? What about **openvpn settings**? etc...

Comment: noone seems to find this post... maybe it could be moved to serverfault? this might be too difficult for regular users...

Comment: I wonder if you've found any solution to this? The concept is surely interesting, even though I'd personally try to avoid putting *NFS* and *unreliable network* in the same sentence.

Comment: Have you considered using Samba vs NFS, or even SSHFS?  The downside to SSHFS vs OpenVPN is OpenVPN can be tuned to provide better throughput.

Comment: Since comments are limited to a small number of characters, it would be impractical to list OpenVPN settings one should use, however what I would recommend is taking a look at the [OpenVPN Wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/openvpn-streamlined-server-setup) I wrote for OpenWrt.  Whereas one will need to dismiss, or substitute for, OpenWrt specific commands, 95% of the Wiki applies to an OpenVPN server running on any OS.

Answer (score 2):

In concurrence with [zagrimsan](https://superuser.com/users/243625/zagrimsan)'s statement that *unreliable network* and *nfs* don't play well together. Your mileage will definitely vary and don't expect any promises, though in general this can work.

OpenVPN across the internet is broadly comparable to a really bad quality, really long cable from wherever you are in the world directly into your private network. NFS was designed with low latency and high quality in mind so this is not the best use case.

The *soft* and *intr* mount options would be advisable since interruptions are quite possible when out and about, especially using the connectivity types you describe. For simplicity, yes you should always use the VPN when connecting to the share, or the server will interpret your in-home and roaming connections as two clients, or more if you get a new IP on VPN reconnect, confusing locking and other concurrency logic.

If your .99 network is already only available via the VPN, then simply pushing any other routes to the client will allow you to enable the VPN in-home.

OpenVPN in TUN mode typically re-issues the same IP address to a client with the same certificate, and whatever DHCP service you are using should hopefully use the static MAC (with OpenVPN's `lladdr` option) to give the same IP on each connection in TAP mode. There is no advantage to TAP here so I would steer clear. You can use the `ifconfig-push` [ccd directive](http://michlstechblog.info/blog/openvpn-set-a-static-ip-address-for-a-client/) if you are using a passphrase instead of certificates

I would first look at TCP for the NFS transport, and UDP for the OpenVPN transport. You absolutely [do not want](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html) both OpenVPN on TCP and NFS on TCP over those shaky connectivity types.

Comment: OpenVPN, if configured correctly, will provide excellent throughput, but most don't bother doing so & 99% of tutorials only configure the bare minimum. Regardless of remote access type, one will always be limited by the ISP upload speed of the remote network. It's not possible for WWAN devices to have a static MAC, as WWAN does not adhere to RFC protocols.  To provide the same IP over OpenVPN, CCD should be configured, TAP should never be utilized for a WWAN device, and **_if_** there is high packet loss, TCP should be utilized for OpenVPN (TCP is utilized for high pkt loss & troubleshooting).

Comment: TCP for NFS, yes that will ensure reliable connectivity, but not for OpenVPN itself. I've yet to see a use case where OpenVPN over TCP is warranted, except for ridiculous requirements like the governments only permitting TCP/443. Any connection reliability should be handled by the application, not OpenVPN which is simply a container for the payload packets.

Comment: As stated in my comment, **there are only two use cases for TCP in OpenVPN**:  **1:** _high packet loss over UDP_; **2:** _Troubleshooting_.  Beyond those two specific use cases, TCP should not be utilized as **TCP cannot efficiently encapsulate itself** _(all SSL VPN traffic is, by default, TCP, of which is encapsulated within UDP packets for transport, and is why MTU [MTU size of 48,000 if using AES256] and Buffer Tuning is recommended)_.  All of the above is spelled out quite clearly in [OpenVPN's documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation.html).